# How to combine two hot IObservable<int>-s so the resulting one gives back sum of one minus sum of others?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

I have two hot observables of integer. I want to combine both of them to a resulting one which always notifies observer with new sum every time a new value come in through either of the observables.

```
Suppose observable1 goes as follows  ....., 3, 5, 9, 10, 16 -->
observable 2 goes like this .............., 1, 3, 2 --->
```

I want resulting one to maintain a sum in a way that adds everything to the sum coming through 1 and subtracts everything coming through 2 so in above example resulting one would go like this

```
..........................................37, 38, 35, 38, 33, 35, 26, 16 --->
```

I am thinking of doing it the following way

```
var result = Observable.Merge(observable1.Scan((p, n) => p + n), 
                             .observable2.Scan((p, n) => p - n)))
                             .Scan((p, n) => p + n);
```

Does anybody know a better way?

Comment: @dtb, editing just made confusion. 16, 16+10=26, 16+10+9=35, 16+10+9-2=33, 16+10+9-2+5=38,16+10+9-2+5-3=35.....

Comment: is 16 at the end of the list? there are two more elements in the observable 1 than observable 2? result should be {16, 26, 35, 33, 38, 35, 38, 37 ,......................}---> not{..........,16, 26, 35, 33, 38, 35, 38, 37} ?

Comment: The indentation is not fun :(

Comment: You are right, the result is actually reversed

Comment: I'm confused. Do you basically want Summation of X - Summation of Y?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Yes and summation has to be updated every time either of the observable reads a value. Because both 1 and 2 are hot observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Merge` and `Scan` for the outer observable, use `CombineLatest`:

```
var result = Observable
    .CombineLatest(
        obs1.Scan(0, (sum, n) => sum + n).StartWith(0), // running sum of first observable
        obs2.Scan(0, (sum, n) => sum + n).StartWith(0), // running sum of second observable
        (sum1, sum2) => sum2 - sum1); // running difference of the 2 sums
```